# Count objects on the basis of foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Suppose

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,...)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,...)
    ...
```

Now how do i get a list of model1 objects with author id and number of objects of model1 where author is author.

For Example

```
[{userid: 1, noofposts: 5}, {userid: 2, noofposts" 1}, ...]
```

I want to use that code in django serializers.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can add e methodSerializrerField in the serializer and the method can return something like this to get the response you are expecting,

```
Model1.objects.values('author','post').annotate(noofposts=Count('posts')).order_by('-nooofposts')
```

Comment: Read the question again.

Comment: Do you mean you need userid as key instead of author ?

Comment: author is user. So author id is user id.